# Models in extension are not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I am developing a custom module for Magento (CE, 1.9) and I'm running into the most basic problem, my models (which should override core models) are not being found/loaded correctly. I have diagnosed this back to Mage.php and can see where it is adding, for example the singleton catalog/layer, and instead of adding the object it only gets a boolean. This causes all subsequent code to fail of course.

I have checked my configuration against [this module creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) and my directories and code all match exactly what is produced, so I'm at a loss!

etc/modules/Namespace_Pricing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Pricing>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Pricing>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Namespace/Pricing/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Pricing>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Pricing>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <pricing>
                <class>Namespace_Pricing_Helper</class>
            </pricing>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <pricing>
                <class>Namespace_Pricing_Model</class>
            </pricing>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_price>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Layer</layer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>-->
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Namespace/Pricing/Model/Catalog/Layer.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
{

}
```

app/code/community/Namespace/Pricing/Model/Catalog/Product/Type/Price.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{

}
```

`Namespace` is not literal, but it's just a string and is correctly cased everywhere used. What else do I need to look at outside these directories? With the module active, in fact just with the rewrites in place in `config.xml`, Magento throws an exception that the model (catalog/layer etc) already exists in the registry, because it only exists as a boolean False when set.

Comment: Code is working for me.Whats your code in model post in question? or check any other extension rewrite same class which one you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `<catalog>` tag twice in your `config.xml` file. In addition to this, there is an ending xml comment piece of code

Change this

```
    <models>
        <pricing>
            <class>Namespace_Pricing_Model</class>
        </pricing>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_price>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Layer</layer>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>-->
    </models>
```

For this

```
    <models>
        <pricing>
            <class>Namespace_Pricing_Model</class>
        </pricing>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Layer</layer>
                <product_type_price>Namespace_Pricing_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
```

Comment: Well the left over comment closing doesn't make any difference, but combining the duplicate <catalog> was the key - thanks very much indeed, the fact Magento doesn't combine them is a good nugget to remember!